# SQL Server MERGE statement with multiple UPDATES

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have a legacy stored procedure in SQL Server that I am trying to update. It is a big procedure, but to illustrate my concern, I will make it simpler.

The procedure is to update a user in `User` table. If it is a new user, they `INSERT`, otherwise `UPDATE` the data. Currently, they use a `MERGE` statement to accomplish this. I have to modify the procedure to handle `PreviousAddress` logic. The procedure needs to check if the user is an existing user, and the address passed in to the procedure is a new address, then we need to put the old address in `PreviousAddress` column and the new address goes in `Address` column.

Here is the current `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE dbo.User AS TARGET
USING
(
    SELECT @USERID as USERID,
    @USERNAME as USERNAME,
    @ADDRESS as ADDRESS,
    @PREVIOUSADDRESS as PREVIOUSADDRESS
) as SOURCE
(
    USERID,
    USERNAME,
    ADDRESS,
    PREVIOUSADDRESS
) ON (TARGET.USERID = SOURCE.USERID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( USERID,
       USERNAME,
       ADDRESS,
       PREVIOUSADDRESS )
    VALUES ( SOURCE.USERID,
       SOURCE.USERNAME,
       SOURCE.ADDRESS,
       SOURCE.PREVIOUSADDRESS )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
       SET USERNAME = SOURCE.USERNAME,
           ADDRESS = SOURCE.ADDRESS,
           PREVIOUSADDRESS = SOURCE.PREVIOUSADDRESS
```

I want to do something like this, of course two `MERGE` statement are not possible but want to know how to achieve similar solution:

```
MERGE dbo.User AS TARGET
    USING
    (
        SELECT @USERID as USERID,
        @USERNAME as USERNAME,
        @ADDRESS as ADDRESS,
        @PREVIOUSADDRESS as PREVIOUSADDRESS
    ) as SOURCE
    (
        USERID,
        USERNAME,
        ADDRESS,
        PREVIOUSADDRESS
    ) ON (TARGET.USERID = SOURCE.USERID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ( USERID,
           USERNAME,
           ADDRESS,
           PREVIOUSADDRESS )
        VALUES ( SOURCE.USERID,
           SOURCE.USERNAME,
           SOURCE.ADDRESS,
           SOURCE.PREVIOUSADDRESS )
    WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.ADDRESS <> SOURCE.ADDRESS THEN
        UPDATE
           SET USERNAME = SOURCE.USERNAME,
               ADDRESS = SOURCE.ADDRESS,
               PREVIOUSADDRESS = TARGET.ADDRESS
    WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.ADDRESS = SOURCE.ADDRESS THEN
        UPDATE
           SET USERNAME = SOURCE.USERNAME,
               ADDRESS = SOURCE.ADDRESS,
               PREVIOUSADDRESS = SOURCE.PREVIOUSADDRESS
```

My current solution is: at the beginning of the procedure, I go and get the current address from the `USER` table for the an existing user and if the address doesn't match, then store the existing address in memory. Then I use this stored address in the end to compare and update (after the MERGE statement is executed).

Something like this:

```
IF @USERID IS NULL AND @ADDRESS IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
  SELECT @CURRENTADDRESS = ADDRESS FROM USER WHERE USERID = @USERID AND ADDRESS <> @ADDRESS
END

<<ORIGINAL MERGE STATEMENT>>

IF @CURRENTADDRESS IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  UPDATE USER SET PREVIOUSADDRESS = @CURRENTADDRESS WHERE USERID = @USERID
END
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem with just the `MERGE` statement?

Comment: Side note - you may consider discontinuing the use of MERGE altogether.  It is [riddled with problems](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE WHEN clause

```
MERGE dbo.User AS TARGET
    USING
    (
        SELECT @USERID as USERID,
        @USERNAME as USERNAME,
        @ADDRESS as ADDRESS,
        @PREVIOUSADDRESS as PREVIOUSADDRESS
    ) as SOURCE
    (
        USERID,
        USERNAME,
        ADDRESS,
        PREVIOUSADDRESS
    ) ON (TARGET.USERID = SOURCE.USERID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ( USERID,
           USERNAME,
           ADDRESS,
           PREVIOUSADDRESS )
        VALUES ( SOURCE.USERID,
           SOURCE.USERNAME,
           SOURCE.ADDRESS,
           SOURCE.PREVIOUSADDRESS )
    WHEN MATCHED 
        UPDATE
           SET USERNAME = SOURCE.USERNAME,
               ADDRESS = SOURCE.ADDRESS,
               PREVIOUSADDRESS = (CASE WHEN  TARGET.ADDRESS <> SOURCE.ADDRESS THEN TARGET.ADDRESS
               ELSE SOURCE.PREVIOUSADDRESS END)
```

Comment: I didn't realize I could use `CASE WHEN`. What if the address field is split into ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, CITY, STATE and ZIP. Do you recommend using `CASE WHEN` for each of those fields in `UPDATE` or there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: no, CASE WHEN allows only scalar values, so so need for every, you could try qan UPDATE JOIN that bshould help if all have the same condition, but this is a new question